# how to return all of the content whilst adding it on as a string

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, return-value, return-type

```
import java.util.*;
 public class Help {

 public static String fromSender(ArrayList<Message> messageList, String pname){

    for(int i=0; i<messageList.size(); i++){

        if(messageList.get(i).getSender().equals(pname)){
            pname = messageList.get(i).getContent() + " ";
        }
    }
    return pname;
   }

 public static void main(String[] args){
     ArrayList<Message> messageList= new ArrayList<Message>();
     messageList.add(new Message("UKMark","UKJohn","message1 "));
     messageList.add(new Message("John","Don","ah"));
     messageList.add(new Message("UKMark","UKJohn","message2 "));
     System.out.print(fromSender(messageList, "UKMark") );
  }
}
```

I tried to test this code which is meant to print message1 message2 however it only prints message1, why does it do this when it goes through the whole array and storing it in pname

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite the value in variable `pname` in your `fromSender` function by assigning it the first matched message's content in this line of code `pname = messageList.get(i).getContent() + " ";`. So in the rest of the loops, the `pname` is actually the first matched message content and no longer 'UKMark' so the second message's sender won't match.

Just use another variable to return from your `fromSender` function.

```
public static String fromSender(ArrayList<Message> messageList, String pname){

    String result = "";
    for(int i=0; i<messageList.size(); i++){

        if(messageList.get(i).getSender().equals(pname)){
            result += messageList.get(i).getContent() + " ";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `=`, use `+=` inside your if statement. Issue will be resolved.

But ideally you should be using a separate String variable to maintain what you return, instead of using of the passed parameter, especially when it was supposed to meant something else than you are using it as.